# Calculating average for values in 2 variables in an apperio.io database

Tags: javascript, average

I'm relatively new with both appery.io and javascript.  My app will query dbase and then calculate average a and average b for values in variables a and b.  My script is running and the output is formatted correctly but the average calculated is not correct.

Can you help me with my below script?

```
var val=0;
if(data.length) {

    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

        val+=+data[i].grade_courtesy;
        val+=+data[i].grade_overall;

    }

    val=val/data.length;

}

Appery("courtesy_grade").text(val);
Appery("overall_grade").text(val);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need separate variables for courtesy and overall.

```
var courtesyVal = 0,
    overallVal = 0,
    i;

if(data.length) {

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        courtesyVal += data[i].grade_courtesy;
        overallVal += data[i].grade_overall;

    }

    courtesyVal = courtesyVal / data.length;
    overallVal = overallVal / data.length;

}

Appery("courtesy_grade").text(courtesyVal);
Appery("overall_grade").text(overallVal);
```

Comment: Hello, output seems to repeat incorrect averages.  In other words, same answer for each variable and both incorrect.  The code looks correct, maybe something else wrong.  Stumped...

Comment: You sure data[i].grade_courtesy and data[i].grade_overall are what you think they are?

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you.  My two variables were inadvertently coded as string.  1 more thing, any ideas on how I can round answer to 1 decimal place.

Comment: I updated my code to ouput a letter grade instead of gpa.  The logic for calculating average is working, but my second condition is not executing.  So output says, 'variable 1' average = C [true] but 'variable 2' average = 2.4 [false]

Comment: if (courtesyVal >= 4 || overallVal >= 4) {
    courtesyVal = ("A") || overallVal("A");
} else if (courtesyVal >= 3 || overallVal >= 3) {
    courtesyVal = ("B") || overallVal("B");
} else if (courtesyVal >= 2 || overallVal >= 2) {
    courtesyVal = ("C") || overallVal("C");
} else if (courtesyVal >= 1 || overallVal >= 1) {
    courtesyVal = ("D") || overallVal("D");
} else {
    courtesyVal = ("F") || overallVal("F");
}

Appery("courtesy_grade").text(courtesyVal);
Appery("overall_grade").text(overallVal);